# body null when accessed from another method

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have a contact listener that handles contact between two box2d bodies. I am accessing the bodies from the Contacter in the HelloWorldLayer since box2d recommends that contacting bodies should be saved and changes implemented after the timestep. Please see the code below:

Contacter.h:

```
#import "CCPhysicsSprite.h"

@interface Contacter : CCPhysicsSprite {

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray* arrayOfBodies;
@property(nonatomic, assign) CCPhysicsSprite* spriteToDestroy;


-(void)physicsSpritesContact:(CCPhysicsSprite*)onePhysicsSprite otherSprite:(CCPhysicsSprite*)twoPhysicsSprite;

@end
```

Contacter.mm:

```
#import "Contacter.h"
#import "Box2D.h"

@implementation Contacter

@synthesize arrayOfBodies = _arrayOfBodies;
@synthesize spriteToDestroy = _spriteToDestroy;

-(void)destroyBodies:(b2Body*)body   {
    _arrayOfBodies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSValue *bodyValue = [NSValue valueWithPointer:body];
    [_arrayOfBodies addObject:bodyValue];
}

-(void)physicsSpritesContact:(CCPhysicsSprite*)onePhysicsSprite otherSprite:   (CCPhysicsSprite*)twoPhysicsSprite; {
int firstTag = onePhysicsSprite.tag;
int secondTag = twoPhysicsSprite.tag;

if (((firstTag == 90) && (secondTag == 101 )) || ((firstTag == 101) && (secondTag == 90))) {

    if (tag1 == 90) {
        [self destroyBodies:onePhysicsSprite.b2Body];// adds body to array to be destroyed
        spriteToDestroy = onePhysicsSprite; // taking note of sprite to be destroyed

    }
    else if (tag2 == 90)   {
        [self destroyBodies:twoPhysicsSprite.b2Body];
        spriteToDestroy = twoPhysicsSprite;
    }
}
```

}

The following method within HelloWorldLayer.mm is called in the update method:

```
-(void)removeDestroyedBodiesAndSprites  {
bodyContact = [Contacter node];    
if ([bodyContact arrayOfBodies]) {


for (NSValue* bodyValue in [bodyContact arrayOfBodies]) {
    b2Body *removeBody;
    removeBody = (b2Body*)[bodyValue pointerValue];

    world->DestroyBody(removeBody);
    removeBody = NULL;
    [self removeChild:[bodyContact spriteToDestroy]];
       }
    }
}
```

There is contact but the sprite is not removed and body is not destroyed in removeDestroyedBodiesAndSprites. After testing with a CCLOG I found that the for loop was not satisfied meaning that the arrayOfBodies could be null. Which is surprising since the contact was established. I would appreciate your assistance.

**UPDATED**

Below is the contact listener:

TestContactListener.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "GameObjects.h"
#import "Contacter.h"


class TestContactListener : public b2ContactListener    {
public:
    Contacter* contacter;

    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
};
```

TestContactListener.mm:

```
#import "TestContactListener.h"

void TestContactListener:: BeginContact(b2Contact *contact)
{
    contacter = [Contacter node];

    b2Fixture       *fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture       *fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
    b2Body          *fixtureABody = fixtureA->GetBody();
    b2Body          *fixtureBBody = fixtureB->GetBody();

    CCPhysicsSprite* physicsSprite = (CCPhysicsSprite*)fixtureABody->GetUserData();
    CCPhysicsSprite* physicsSprite2 = (CCPhysicsSprite*)fixtureBBody->GetUserData();

    [contacter physicsSpritesContact:physicsSprite otherSprite:physicsSprite2];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this from the `destroyBodies` method to an `init` method, so it is only called once:

```
_arrayOfBodies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: I made an init as you recommended but now I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error pointing to the line  `contacter = [Contacter node];`  in the `TestContactListener.mm` class. Please see the updated code with the contact listener class above.

Comment: Is Contacter a singleton? What does your [Contacter node] call look like?

Comment: I was able to solve it. Initializing the contacter every time the BeginContact recognized a contact whiles re-initializing it in the HelloWorldLayer init method was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at your destroyBodies method. You create a new array, replacing any existing array, every time you call it. Therefore you will only destroy the last body you passed in to that method.

If you are not using ARC you'll also leak all the replaced arrays.

Comment: don't create a new array every time